# Using System.Web.Caching.Cache

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching

I am trying to use the Cache, but get the error below. How can I properly use the Cache?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
x = System.DateTime.Now.ToString();
 if (Cache["ModifiedOn"] == null) { // first time so no key/value in Cache
    Cache.Insert("ModifiedOn", x); // inserts the key/value pair "Modified On", x            
 }
 else { // Key/value pair already exists in the cache
     x = Cache["ModifiedOn"].ToString();
 } }
```

> 'System.Web.Caching.Cache' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'

Comment: `Cache` is a type. Surely you need to create an instance of `Cache` somewhere to use it?

Comment: See these links, one is from microsoft
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478965.aspx#aspnet-cachingtechniquesbestpract_topic4 and this 
http://chalaki.com/asp-net-data-caching-how-to-use-the-system-web-caching-cache-object-2/73/

They have used same syntax.

Comment: Please show YOUR CODE and not the sample you found online.  Then we might see what's wrong.

Answer (score 45):

[`System.Web.Caching.Cache`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.aspx): this is the implementation of .NET caching.

[`System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.cache.aspx): this is the instance of that implementation, that lives in the application domain.

I think you want to use the second one if you are not in the code behind of an aspx page. Use Cache if you are in the code behind of an aspx page.

You can also use `Page.Cache.Insert` directly that has a reference to the `System.Caching.Cache` through the page object. All this point to the same application cache which are global for all users.

Comment: if you use HttpContext.Current.Cache["Item"] = object, its not working?

Comment: I think you are not in the page class (code behind of an asp.net page) and thats why the Cache does not work directly. In the code behind, you can use the syntax you mentioned in the links above.

Comment: Oh yes .. nice catch. I am making a class library to interact with cache. How can I do that in a separate class?

Comment: instead of using "Cache" directly, just use "System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache". You may need to add a reference to system.web assembly depending on what your library is.

Comment: If your application structure is a WEB FARM, will the same .NET implementation work or you have to tweak it?

Answer (score 0):

Have somewhere that the class stores the HttpContext when it is initialized by new, or with an `Init()` method

Then use the `HttpContext.Current.Cache`

Or: Make methods to read and write to the cache with a parameter `currentcache`, and document that so with sample code where it is called with `HttpContext.Current.Cache`